# Finding the minimum value of a rational function.

Tags: number-theory, optimization, rational-functions

Prove that if $x$ is real and $a>c$ & $b>c$ the minimum value of $$\frac{(a+x)(b+x)}{(c+x)} ;Given\space( x>-c)$$ is $$({\sqrt{a-c}+\sqrt{b-c \space}})^2$$

I tried using minima condition but the expression was too complicated to arrange and solve .How can this be solved algebraically? Please give answers/suggestions. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you write out what you have done? Perhaps you made a slight calculation mistake, or didn't notice a way to simplify the equation.

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually this question is meant to be solved algebraically(without the knowledge of calculus) and you may notice it gets quite lengthy going by the calculus method although we might get the answer

Comment: All the more reason to write out what you have done, if you want the solution approached in a particular way. Otherwise, most people will just differentiate and solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand and simplify (or rather, do partial fraction decomposition), we get that

$$ \frac{ (a+x)(b+x)}{c+x} = (x+c) + \frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{x+c} + a+b-2c $$

Apply AM-GM to the first two terms to conclude that

$$ (x+c) + \frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{x+c} + a+b-2c \geq 2 \sqrt{ (a-c)(b-c)  } + a+b-2c = \left( \sqrt{a-c} + \sqrt{b-c} \right)^2$$

Comment: Awesome. Can you tell me how did that click?(for future problems like these.)

Comment: As I said, it depended on what approach you wanted. Since you wanted 'algebraically', which I interpreted as classical inequalities, the main difficulty is dealing with the $x+c$ in the denominator. This can be gotten rid of if we had an $x$ around, so we use partial fractions. Of course, the proper way to get rid of $\frac{N}{x+c} $ is to use $x+c$, so I adjusted the constants for it to work.

Comment: Got that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite the top as $(a-c+c+x)(b-c+c+x)$ and let $y=c+x$. We end up with something of shape $\frac{(p+y)(q+y)}{y}$, where $p$ and $q$ are positive.

You will end up needing to minimize $\frac{pq}{y}+y$, which is probably  familiar.

Comment: Nice way to simplify. Thanks :)